# SQLite DB in Shiny app failing in EC2 and with Docker not working: error readonly database

Tags: r, docker, sqlite, amazon-ec2, shiny

I have a shiny app that I have deployed in the following way:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:latest

## copy files
# Additional packages
COPY install_packages.R /install_packages.R
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

## install packages 
RUN Rscript /install_packages.R

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libglpk40
    
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev python3.11 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Then in my **EC2** I clone the repo with the app code and execute like this:

```
sudo docker container run --rm -p 3838:3838 -v /home/ubuntu/zto_shiny:/srv/shiny-server/zto_shiny zto_beta:1.2.0
```

Inside the `zto_shiny` directory there is a SQLite `database.db` file. Locally it works perfectly; in two different machines I tested. But in the** EC2** I can read the database and load it into the app, but when I want to modify o create a new record I have this error message:

```
Warning: Error in : attempt to write a readonly database
```

I've already tried changing ownership and modifying permissions with `chown` and `chmod`.

Any guesss?

I believe that there is an overall "Firewall" because I find several "permission denied".